# How to convert a YAML sequence to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I need to loop through a YAML sequence and build an array with the sequence items.

I assume my YAML sequence should look like this in my `config/redis`:

```
redis:
  host:
  port:
  sentinels:
    - 1.34.79.100
    - 1.45.79.101
    - 1.46.79.102
```

In my `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` I have a `configure_client` block that looks like:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { 
    master_name: 'util-master'
    sentinels: [
      "sentinel://#{first_redis_sentinel}:23679"
      "sentinel://#{second_redis_sentinel}:23679"
      "sentinel://#{third_redis_sentinel}:23679"
    ],
    failover_reconnect_timeout: 20,
    url: "redis://#{redis_host}:6379/12" }
end
```

I don't know how to dynamically load the listed Redis sentinels into that array. Do I need to build that array outside of the hash and `configure_client` block?

Comment: Have you looked at the YAML and [Psych documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html)? YAML uses Psych to load and parse the data. You're looking for how to use `load_file`.

Comment: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
require 'yaml'
redis_configuration = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'redis.yml'))

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { 
    master_name: 'util-master'
    sentinels: redis_configuration['redis']['sentinels'].map { |sentinel|
      "sentinel://#{sentinel}:23679"
    },
    failover_reconnect_timeout: 20,
    url: "redis://#{redis_configuration['redis']['host']}:6379/12" 
  }
end
```

Comment: You probably want [`load_file`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file), not `load`. `load` expects a string containing the YAML to parse, whereas `load_file` wants a filename which it then reads and parses. Also, using `config` as the outer variable and also as the block's parameter isn't good practice.

Comment: @theTinMan You are right, thanks. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A YAML string can be converted back into Ruby data like so:

```
1.9.3-p551 :005 > yaml = <<YAML
1.9.3-p551 :006"> redis:
1.9.3-p551 :007">   host:
1.9.3-p551 :008">   port:
1.9.3-p551 :009">   sentinels:
1.9.3-p551 :010">     - 1.34.79.100 
1.9.3-p551 :011">     - 1.45.79.101
1.9.3-p551 :012">     - 1.46.79.102
1.9.3-p551 :013"> YAML
=> "redis:\n  host:\n  port:\n  sentinels:\n    - 1.34.79.100\n    - 1.45.79.101\n    - 1.46.79.102\n"
1.9.3-p551 :014 > YAML.load(yaml)
=> {"redis"=>{"host"=>nil, "port"=>nil, "sentinels"=>["1.34.79.100", "1.45.79.101", "1.46.79.102"]}}
```